# pyqgis: how to get the existing Paletted Raster Layers' color

Tags: pyqgis-3, rendering

```
rasterlayer = QgsRasterLayer(infilename, layername)
renderer = rasterlayer.renderer()
```

rasterlayer is the active layer with renderer type is Palette,
I want to get current Palette Color, how could I do? Is the Attribute in  renderer?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it with .getRgb() method of QColor object:

`rgb_color = renderer.legendSymbologyItems()[-1][1].getRgb()`

This will return you a tuple with (red, green, blue, transparency) values.
Here `renderer.legendSymbologyItems()[-1]` returns you the last class from your palette as a tuple with its (name, PyQt5.QtGui.QColor) values.

P.S. there are also `.getHsv()` and `.getCmyk()` and a couple more methods at your service.

Comment: Thanks, it works well, well done. I can get label and color: legendSymbologyItems()[i][0], legendSymbologyItems()[i][1].getRgb().     But I also want to konw how to get the value in QgsPalettedRasterRenderer.Class(value, color, label) from legendSymbologyItems, can you help me?

Comment: You are welcome. Could you please ask a separate question and clearly specify details there?

Comment: ok! thank you,    new question title:     pyqgis: how i get "value", "color", "label" from existing palette raster layer